# Robust Contour Linearity Mesurment

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have extracted the contours of an image using C++ & OPENCV. I need now to check the linearity of every contour (just checking not detecting lines). So, I can eliminate some contours which are less or more than a threshold.
I found this great paper: http://milos.stojmenovic.com/Publications_files/P0386.pdf
However, The methods are too complex to be implemented in a robust way. It is possible to to perform the linearity check on a set of N random points which works well but without robustness.
Any suggested solutions ? Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by too complex? In the abstract they say that average orientation provide results closest to human perception. That doesn't sound very complex.

Comment: @Trilarion I mean time complexity. It can not be implemented in realtime

Comment: Are you sure it is not implementable in real time. I cannot imagine many simpler and faster measures??

Comment: @Trilarion it depends on how many steps (K). but  I need to choose very large value for K so it will be near converge. Otherwise it will give different solution each time I run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a minAreaRect function get RotatedRect. For line one of the dimensions of RotatedRect is so small.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean arclength ? and about the last and first point how should know them ? because it is closed contours and the begin and the end are the same or almost the same

Comment: thanks but opencv always return contours as closed even it is line, opencv closes the line on itself.

Comment: ok use a minAreaRect function get RotatedRect. For line one of the dimensions of RotatedRect is so small.

Comment: clever solution thank you, I will depend on it but I hope to find more accurate one.